# I don't want users to access a django url path but I still want my home page to use the path

Tags: django, url, path

To be more precise I have the following

```
path('',views.home,name='home'),
path('json', json, name="json"),
```

my home page calls the json file to plot a chart, however if user types in the url '.../json' they can access the json data file. I want users to not have access to the path /json but I still want my home page to access this json path.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not quite possible because when your homepage is loaded by a user, the page tells them to request the json data from your server. The browser sees will make a request for the data, and there is almost no difference between the user going to http://yoursite.com and the browser making a call to http://yoursite.com/json.

One way you could try if the data is only loaded once is to append a single-use token to homepage (which is different for every request) and allow the browser to use this to allow the request.

```
def home(request):
    # do everything
    context['token'] = generate_token()
    session['json_token'] = context['token']
    return render()

def json(request):
    if request.GET.get('token', '') == session['json_token']:
        del session['json_token']
        # generate_data
        return data
    return HttpResponse(status_code=405)
```